# GStreamer - Pipeline how to connect filesrc to qmlglsink

Tags: c++, qt, qml, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm new in the world of GStreamer, so I can't figure out how it works, and how to pair all GstElements.

I want to merge Video (mp4 for example, or any other video format) with qml (from Qt) as an overlay.
[This example](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/qt/qmlsink) works perfectly fine.

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new(NULL);
GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc",NULL);
GstElement *glupload = gst_element_factory_make("glupload",NULL);
GstElement *qmlglsink = gst_element_factory_make("qmlglsink",NULL);

g_assert(src && glupload && qmlglsink);

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, glupload, sink);
gst_element_link_many(src, glupload, sink, NULL);
```

But that example uses `videotestsrc` as Source, I would prefer to use something like `filesrc`.
I tried this code:

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new (NULL);

GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "file-source");
GstElement *parser = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse",NULL);
GstElement *decoder = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264",NULL);
GstElement *colors = gst_element_factory_make("glcolorconvert",NULL);

GstElement *glupload = gst_element_factory_make ("glupload", NULL);
GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("qmlglsink", NULL);

g_assert (src && parser && decoder %% colors && glupload && sink);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (src), "location", "file:///home/test.mp4", NULL);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, parser, decoder, glupload, colors, sink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many (src, parser, decoder, glupload, colors, sink, NULL);
```

It compiles, but the output is just a black screen.

Since I'm not sure how the GStreamer pipeline works, I tried that.

First, get the file from memory with `filesrc`, then parse it with `h265parse` and decode it with `avdec_h264`. Then forward that (I guess raw uncompressed data) to `glupload` and make colors good with `glcolorconvert`, since `qmlglsink` uses **RGBA**, and `avdec_h264` is **I420**. After colors, are adjusted forward it to `qmlglsink` to be displayed in qml.

I'm missing something, and I don't know how to pair `GstElemnts`, as I said I need to pair `filesrc` (any video format) and `qmlglsink`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
    MediaPlayer{
        id: playVideo
        source: "gst-pipeline: filesrc location=/home/root/skim-debris.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_h264 ! qtvideosink"
        autoLoad: true
        autoPlay: true
        playbackRate: 1.0
        loops: 10
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: playVideo
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you need to set state to playing with `gst_element_set_state(m_video_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);`

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to use a `bin` or any of GStreamers auto-pluggers.

But the main issue here is that you try treating an MP4 file as H.264 stream. This cannot work this way. You need to demux media streams from your container.

E.g. the pipeline should be something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! \
h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! glupload ! glcolorconvert ! qmlglsink
```

Comment: I tried using `qtdemux` but it was the same outcome, a black screen. Any other idea? It doesn't have to be H.264...

Comment: Read on at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html?gi-language=c you will to do some debugging then. We know nothing about your media file.